# Can we find a family of sets over the whole space $X$ that is "larger" than the power set of $X$

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

Don't know if the statement in the title is true or not.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No.  Every subset of $X$ is, by definition, in the power set $2^X$ of $X$, so for any set $A$ of subsets of $X$, there is always an injection $A \rightarrow 2^X$ by sending each set to itself.  This means $A$ cannot be larger under pretty much any reasonable definition of "larger".

Answer (score 2):

The power set is the set of all subsets of $X$, so we cannot find a family of sets that are in $X$ such that this family has a larger cardinality..(Anything from that family would be subsets of  $X$ that would necessarily be in the power set of $X$)